UserWarning: Mutation on a buffer in the model is detected. ExecuTorch assumes buffers that are mutated in the graph have a meaningless initial state
I have exported model to Executorch program, and the file is saved correctly in directory. But I enountered warning like this
# To see more debug info, please use `graph_module.print_readable()`
Model successfully exported to model.pte
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/executorch/exir/emit/_emitter.py:1512: UserWarning: Mutation on a buffer in the model is detected. ExecuTorch assumes buffers that are mutated in the graph have a meaningless initial state, only the shape and dtype will be serialized.
  warnings.warn(

Yes, the warning was not completed, so I was confused about whether this warning would have a big impact on the program I was going to run or not.
I use T4 in google colab to execute this function.

def quantize_model(model: nn.Module, example_inputs: tuple) -> nn.Module:
 
    print(f"Original model architecture:\n{model}")
    
    # Initialize quantizer with symmetric quantization configuration
    quantizer = XNNPACKQuantizer()
    operator_config = get_symmetric_quantization_config(is_per_channel=False)
    quantizer.set_global(operator_config)
    
    # Prepare model for quantization
    pre_autograd_model = export_for_training(model, example_inputs).module()
    prepared_model = prepare_pt2e(pre_autograd_model, quantizer)
    
    # Calibrate and convert the model
    prepared_model(*example_inputs)
    quantized_model = convert_pt2e(prepared_model)
    
    print(f"Quantized model architecture:\n{quantized_model}")
    return quantized_model

def export_to_executorch(model: nn.Module, example_inputs: tuple, output_path: str):

    edge_program = to_edge_transform_and_lower(
        export(model, example_inputs),
        compile_config=EdgeCompileConfig(_check_ir_validity=True),
        partitioner=[XnnpackPartitioner()]
    )
    
    # Convert to executorch program
    executorch_program: exir.ExecutorchProgramManager = edge_program.to_executorch(
        ExecutorchBackendConfig(passes=[])
    )
    
    # Save the program to file
    with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
        file.write(executorch_program.buffer)
        print(f"Model successfully exported to {output_path}")

def main():
    # Define example inputs
    example_inputs = (torch.randn(1, 1, 256, 256),)
    
    # Create and quantize model
    model = ResEmoteNet()  # Assuming this class is defined elsewhere
    quantized_model = quantize_model(model, example_inputs)
    
    # Export the quantized model
    export_to_executorch(
        model=quantized_model,
        example_inputs=example_inputs,
        output_path="model.pte"
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

